# Time Bug (My Script) PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I've got this weird bug happening.  I'm basically just adding a few minutes to a time formatted like '12:20pm' with the following function...

```
function calc_arb_time($startTime, $amount){
        $startTime = date('Y-m-d') . substr($startTime,0,-2);
        $startTime = strtotime($startTime);


        $seconds = $amount*60;
        $startTime += $seconds;
        $newStartTime = date('g:ia', $startTime);
        return($newStartTime);
    }

echo calc_arb_time('12:20pm',20); // <-- this returns 12:40pm which is great

echo calc_arb_time('1:20pm',20); // this returns 1:40am... Why the AM??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing anything to preserve the *am* or *pm* part? Also don't worry about the date part if you're not going to use it anyway.

This code is simpler and it works fine:

```
function calc_arb_time($startTime, $amount){
    $startTime = strtotime('+'.$amount.' minutes', strtotime($startTime));
    return date('g:ia', $startTime);
}
echo calc_arb_time('12:20pm',20).PHP_EOL;
echo calc_arb_time('1:20pm',20);
```

Also I'm not sure the name of the function reflects what it does. You should consider changing it.

Comment: function name means calculate arbitrary time... thanks for your input :)

Comment: @Jascha Well, it isn't really arbitrary if you know the output from the parameters :). For the input: No problem, and I would recommend taking your time to play a bit with `strtotime`. I can be a real time saver if you know how to use it.

Comment: It is arbitrary when I have 2 other functions adding specific bits of time.  Every once in a while I have to add an arbitrary few minutes.  So I call on my function calc_arb_time().

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('g:ia', '12:20pm');
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT20M'));
echo $date->format('H:i:s');

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('g:ia', '1:20pm');
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT20M'));
echo $date->format('H:i:s');
```

Prints:

```
12:40:00
13:40:00
```

Comment: I'd love to use this one but I'm < php 5.2